# Added WCF Service Reference. But where is Reference.svcmap and Reference.cs?

Tags: wcf

I am accessing a WCF service from a client. The client is configured properly to access the proxy. However, I am expecting to find 2 files (reference.svcmap, reference.cs) under the SERVICE REFERENCES folder in Visual Studio 2012. Instead, I can only see a localhost (this refers to the namespace of the client proxy created).
From where do I see reference.svcmap and reference.cs?
[image: WCF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to highlight the project (`ClientIndigo`) in the solution explorer, and then click on the `Show All Files` button in the toolbar at the top of Solution Explorer.

In Visual Studio 2010, this looked like this (haven't upgraded to VS2012 myself):

[image]

Those files are "nested" below the service reference, and not shown by default.